# minifi java agent uses high CPU on AIX

Tags: apache-nifi

I noticed that the TailFile processor consumes CPU on the AIX operating system.

Can I do anything to reduce the consumption?

```
Processors:
- id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  name: TailFile
  class: org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.TailFile
  max concurrent tasks: 1
  scheduling strategy: TIMER_DRIVEN
  scheduling period: 0 sec
  penalization period: 30 sec
  yield period: 1 sec
  run duration nanos: 0
  auto-terminated relationships list:
  - success
  Properties:
    File Location: Local
    File to Tail: *.log
    Initial Start Position: Beginning of File
    Rolling Filename Pattern:
    tail-base-directory: /WorkingDir85/log/
    tail-mode: Multiple files
    tailfile-lookup-frequency: 10 minutes
    tailfile-maximum-age: 24 hours
    tailfile-recursive-lookup: 'false'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scheduling period is 0 sec which basically means run as fast as possible. Setting to something like '10 ms' or even '1 ms' should lighten the CPU usage.

Comment: Thanks, Bryan, do you mean 10 sec or in 10 ms?

Comment: ms as in milliseconds.. just a very slight delay should make a difference